# Magento 2 WebAPI json encode

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api, json, webapi

I'm returning JSON via an endpoint in Magento 2 this bit of JSON looks like the following:

```
    $new_json = [
        'component_1' => '[{....}]', 
        'component_2' => '[{...}]'
    ];
    return $new_json;
```

The endpoint works, but it returns the following:

```
0: "...."
1: "...."
```

Now I can pass the JSON into **[ ]** to return the following, but this isn't what I want:

```
[0]:
component_1: "...."
component_2: "...."
```

My issue is I need to return the JSON with **key** and **value**, not **0 and 1** nor a sub value e.g. [0]

Is there a setting for the endpoint to stop it encoding the JSON like this? Or is there something I need to do to return it in the way that I want?

Thanks.

Comment: try this 
    return [$new_json] ;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Problem Summary:** You have a **PHP Array** and you want to return it as a **JSON Object**. When you return your **PHP Array**, it gets converted to a **JSON Array**, which does not support **non-sequential keys**. So your keys get ignored and you end up with a sequential array of your values.

**Solution Summary:** You need to return a **PHP Object** in order to have a **JSON Object** in your response.

**Solution Example**

Please check following example that returns a sample Components object.

**/Api/Data/ComponentsInterface.php**

```
<?php
namespace Company\Components\Api\Data;

/**
 * Interface ComponentsInterface
 */
interface ComponentsInterface
{
    /**
     * Get component 1
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getComponent1();

    /**
     * Get component 2
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getComponent2();
}
```

**/Api/ComponentsManagamentInterface.php**

```
<?php
namespace Company\Components\Api;

/**
 * Components Management interface
 */
interface ComponentsManagementInterface
{
    /**
     * @return \Company\Components\Api\Data\ComponentsInterface
     */
    public function getComponents();
}
```

**/etc/webapi.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Webapi:etc/webapi.xsd">
    <route url="/V1/components" method="GET">
        <service class="Company\Components\Api\ComponentsManagementInterface" method="getComponents"/>
    </route>
</routes>
```

**/Model/Components.php**

```
<?php
namespace Company\Components\Model;

/**
 * Components model
 */
class Components extends \Magento\Framework\DataObject implements \Company\Component\Api\Data\ComponentsInterface
{
    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function getComponent1() 
    {
        return $this->getData('component1');
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function getComponent2()
    {
        return $this->getData('component2');
    }
}
```

**/Model/ComponentsManagement.php**

```
<?php
namespace Company\Components\Model;

/**
 * Components Management
 */
class ComponentsManagement implements \Company\Components\Api\ComponentsManagementInterface
{
    /**
    * @var \Company\Components\Api\Data\ComponentsInterfaceFactory
    */
    protected $_componentsFactory;

    /**
    * ComponentsManagement constructor.
    * @param \Company\Components\Api\Data\ComponentsInterfaceFactory $_componentsFactory
    */
    public function __construct(\Company\Components\Api\Data\ComponentsInterfaceFactory $_componentsFactory)
    {
        $this->_componentsFactory = $_componentsFactory;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function getComponents()
    {
        $components = $this->_componentsFactory->create();
        $components->setData([
            'component1' => '[{....}]',
            'component2' => '[{....}]'
            ]);
        return $components;
    }
}
```

**/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Company\Components\Api\Data\ComponentsInterface"
                type="Company\Components\Model\Components"/>
    <preference for="Company\Components\Api\ComponentsManagementInterface"
                type="Company\Components\Model\ComponentsManagement"/>
</config>
```

With above example, when you `GET` `http://magento/rest/V1/components` it will return following JSON Object:

```
{"component_1":"[{....}]","component_2":"[{....}]"}
```

Comment: This answer is absolutely fantastic. How would i go about modifying the 'component1' to be 'something-1' ?

Comment: @andyjones You may use underscore, but dashes are not allowed in such naming, please review Magento\Framework\Reflection\DataObjectProcessor::buildOutputDataArray and Magento\Framework\Reflection\FieldNamer::getFieldNameForMethodName methods it will make more sense.

Comment: According to the `getFieldNameForMethodName` method, the response would use underscores. `component_1` and `component_2` instead of `component1` and `component2`

Comment: What does the `ComponentsInterfaceFactory` file look like?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in your controller.

```
protected $resultJsonFactory;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory
){   
    parent::__construct($context);
    $this->resultJsonFactory   = $resultJsonFactory;
}

public function execute()
{
    $result = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();
    $data = array('component_1' => '[{....}]', 'component_2' => '[{...}]');
    $result->setData($data);
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: The question is based on WebAPI, not a controller.